# Issues with LINES and COLUMNS on new AlmaLinux 9 install (using Putty)

Tags: bash, terminal, ncurses

I seem to be having an odd issue on Almalinux 9 that I have been unable to straighten out.

It looks like the LINES and COLUMNS variables are not set full size for interactive login shells, though they are set full size for interactive non-login shells.  This has the unfortunate side-effect of certain tools such as `vim`, `less`, `man` do not seem to function properly when a user logs in (I get an interactive, non-login, root shell when I activate the console on my VM provided by `qemu-guest-agent`).

I have not experienced this issue on any previous deployments, and searching around I found some information about those values being automatically set by the shell (I am using `bash` v5.1.8).  I have confirmed that the shell option `checkwinsize` is set `on` for all interactive shells through `/etc/bashrc`, but cannot see any changes when attempting to resize the terminal (apparently this seems to only affect Putty terminals and only on Almalinux 9).

I am running the following alias (located in `/tmp/size.sh`) in each session to try to show what my problem is:

```
alias test_size="echo -e \
    \"login: \$(shopt -q login_shell && echo 'yes' || echo 'no') \
    \ninteractive: \$([[ -t 0 || -p '/dev/stdin' ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no') \
    \n\$(id) \
    \n\$(tty) \$TERM \${COLUMNS}x\${LINES} \
    \""
```

Default console from KVM has correct full screen size (COLUMNS=425, LINES=79):

```
bash-5.1# . /tmp/size.sh
bash-5.1# test_size
login: no
interactive: yes
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0
/dev/pts/0 putty-256color 425x79
```

Non-login shell is also correct size:

```
bash-5.1# su test2
[test2@files01 /]$ . /tmp/size.sh
[test2@files01 /]$ test_size
login: no
interactive: yes
uid=1001(test2) gid=1001(test2) groups=1001(test2) context=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0
/dev/pts/0 putty-256color 425x79
[test2@files01 /]$
exit
```

Login shell has a terribly small size (COLUMNS=80, LINES=24):

```
bash-5.1# su - test2
[test2@files01 ~]$ . /tmp/size.sh
[test2@files01 ~]$ test_size
login: yes
interactive: yes
uid=1001(test2) gid=1001(test2) groups=1001(test2) context=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0
/dev/pts/0 putty-256color 80x24
[test2@files01 ~]$
logout
```

While typing this up, I found that the terminal on a different computer was behaving correctly and responding to resizes.

Properly sized interactive login shell:

```
[root@files01 ~]# . /tmp/size.sh 
[root@files01 ~]# test_size
login: yes  
interactive: yes    
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023    
/dev/pts/1 xterm-256color 238x58
```

So this now feels like it might be an issue with `TERM=putty-256color`, but I am unsure as the same terminal works fine for my other deployments.  I have `ncurses-base-6.2-10.20210508` providing `putty-256color` terminfo which appears to be the newest version offered in Almalinux 9.  I have a rolling distribution using newer `ncurses` terminfo (v6.4.20231202) that is behaving correctly and properly resizing when using Putty.

My question would be how can I get the proper full screen sizes and working `checkwinsize` on all terminals for all logins?  I have not seen this particular issue on any other installs I have (mostly CentOS 7/8, Debian 10/11/12, and OpenSUSE Tumbleweed).  I am hoping to avoid having to hardcode LINES and COLUMNS sizes for each user.  I can provide any further information required to help.

Thanks